# How to make leftBarButtonItem looking like backBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem, backbarbuttonitem

The default solvings are not appropriate:

1. to change the previous ViewController title - I need to make my own function controlling the button touches up
2. to make a leftBarButtonItem and hide backBarButtonItem - leftBarButtonItem doesn't look like a default backBarButtonItem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's an example to create a custom leftBarButtonItem:

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backbutton.png"];
UIButton *aButton = [UIbutton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[aButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
aButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,buttonImage.size.width,buttonImage.size.height);
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(aSelector) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aButton];
self.navigationItem.leftButtonItem = backButton;
```

Hope it helps...

**Edit:**

Try this...

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.jpg"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(aSelector)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

I don't remember what type of button is the backbutton, try to change the default style to other. Good luck!

Comment: thanks, I will use this if there are wouldn't any other way. But I hoped to make it more flexible (when it depends on an image and a style of the backBarButtonItem only and doesn't depend on the image resources)

Comment: Your second example is much worse because sdk doesn't allow to set an image and a title for this button at once. So I should make different images for all the labels. Is that you want to advice me?

Comment: Well... I have not looked all styles and types of buttons that navigationbars can have... could you try to change the UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered for another style? maybe there is some style that is like the go back button... and then you could start with a initWithTitle instead the initWithImage. I cannot make more samples because I don't have a Mac now, later i'll try it!

Comment: You can use a virtual machine and/or "Hack OS"

Comment: I meant that I only have a mac to try it when I'm at job :)

Comment: if you use [UIButton buttonWithType:101]; you get the backButton style, however it is an undocumented feature.

Comment: Also, here is a good XCF image of the back button: http://elucidatedbinary.com/blog/2012/10/16/ios-back-button-image/

Comment: This is a very nice and workable solution: http://www.hkwebentrepreneurs.com/2013/11/ios-prevent-back-button-navigating-to.html

Answer (score 0):

Just create a custom `barbuttonitem` and customize it with a picture similar to the back button item.
You can get its text from the view controllers in the navigation stack.

Then handle the taps to implement the desired effect

Comment: Can you put here more concrete example?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign your custom views as the bar buttons to your navigation controller, like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:yourCustomizedControl];
[yourCustomizedControl release];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customItem;
[customItem release];
```

Check [this Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW3) for a more detailed explanation, if you want.

Comment: As I have understood you I need to change the backBarButtonItem title, then I need to convert this one to UIView and assign it to a leftBarButtonItem. But how?

Comment: What I would do is to create a simple UIButton, customize this the way I want it to look like, I mean give it a background image, a title, etc.. You can find an image that's similar to the backBarButtonItem and assign this to your newly created UIButton. And then assign a target action to this UIButton so that it does what you'd like to do when it's tapped. And finally, assign this UIButton as the leftBarButton of your nav. controller as described above.

Comment: Now I think It would be better to delete the leftBarButtonItem and put its function into viewWillDisapear

Comment: ok then. at least now you know about the other alternatives :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hack to add a back-like button:

```
UINavigationItem* backNavigationItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"];
[_navigationBar pushNavigationItem:backNavigationItem animated:NO];
[backNavigationItem release];
```

You can add more items (such like title, right button) this way:

```
UINavigationItem *navigationItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"];
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = // Some UIBarButtonItem
[_navigationBar pushNavigationItem:navigationItem animated:NO];
[navigationItem release];
```

Comment: I never had a rejection because of this

Comment: It looks like this solution uses a "custom" UINavigationBar (`_navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:...]; [self.view addSubview:_navigationBar]; _navigationBar.items = ...; _navigationBar.delegate = self`) instead of `self.navigationController.navigationBar`. You'll need to implement UINavigatonBarDelegate appropriately.